# How to fill 2 d array dynamically

Tags: java, arrays

I want to display resultset value with this pattern:

`Object rowData[][] = { { url , tags , text  }, { url , tags , text  } };`

My code is:

```
while (res.next()) {
    String url = res.getString(1);
    String tags = res.getString(2);
    String text = res.getString(3);
}
Object rowData[][] = { { "Row1-Column1", "Row1-Column2", "Row1-Column3" },
                { "Row2-Column1", "Row2-Column2", "Row2-Column3" } };

Object columnNames[] = { "URL", "Tag Information", "Text" };
JTable table = new JTable(rowData, columnNames);`
```

Comment: Please, use `that style for your code`. More readable.

Comment: Could you please describe a bit more for what do you understand by dynamically. Because it's not clear enough to understand what you want!

Comment: @Parth I want to add reslut set values in array "rowData" if the result set return  two values then the array will be   Object rowData[][] = { { url , tags , text  }, { url , tags , text  } };    url , tags , text are my database coloum names

Comment: Why does it need to be dynamic?

Comment: @Christoffer Passer every time result set will give different value thats why according to that i need to create array.

Comment: What do you mean by every time? Every time the table is created or will the table be altered after creation?

Answer (score 1):

Use a List to store each file of the data, then convert the list into an Array:

```
List<Object[]> data = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
while (res.next()) {
    data.add(new Object[]{res.getString(1), res.getString(2),res.getString(3)});
}

Object[][] rowData = data.toArray(new Object[0][0]);
JTable table = new JTable(rowData, columnNames);
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this simple example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int rows    = 3; //res.getCount() ?
    int columns = 3;

    Object[][] rawData = new Object[rows][columns];

    for(int row = 0; row < rows; row++){
        rawData[row][0] = row + " - url";
        rawData[row][1] = row + " - tags";
        rawData[row][2] = row + " - text";
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(rawData[0])); // print first row
}
```

*string concatenation inside of loop is a very bad idea, but this should be just an example*

Answer (score 0):

**Below is conde snippet which can be used to achieve what you want.**

```
int rowcount = 0;
if (res.last()) {
    rowcount = res.getRow();
    res.beforeFirst();
}
Object rowData[][] = new Object[rowcount][];
int count = 0;
while (res.next()) {
    rowData[count] = new Object[]    {res.getString(1),res.getString(1),res.getString(3)};  
    count++;
}
Object columnNames[] = { "URL", "Tag Information", "Text" };
JTable table = new JTable(rowData, columnNames);
```